# How to find name of the file with particular extesion in array

Tags: php

I have multiples values in array and i want get one of name which in array.

```
Ex: - $val = array('test.mp4','abc.avi','xyz.3gp','abc.csv');
```

Now i want get the name of `'abc.csv'` in `$name`.

Please help me to find the value which is ending with extension `.csv`.

Comment: You mean you want to get the file name that has extension of `.csv`?

Comment: @MuthaFury :- Yes Please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this simple code can help

```
$val = array('test.mp4','abc.avi','xyz.3gp','abc.csv');
$extension = '.csv'; 
$name = '';

foreach ($val as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, $extension) !== false) {
    $name[] = $value;
}
} 

print_r($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$list = array('test.mp4','abc.avi','xyz.3gp','abc.csv');
$name = '';
foreach ($list as $item) {
    if (strrpos($item, '.csv') === 3) {
        $name = $item;
    }
}
echo $name;
```

Comment: awww late by few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $val = array('test.mp4', 'abc.avi', 'xyz.3gp', 'abc.csv');

    foreach ($val as $value) {
        $tmp = strrpos($value, ".csv");
        echo substr($value, 0, $tmp );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($val as $value) {
   $extension = explode(".", $value);
   if($extension[1] == "csv"){
      echo $value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($val as $item) {
   $file_extensions = explode(".", $value);
   if(end($file_extensions) == 'csv'){
      $allCSVFilse[] = $item;
   }
}

print_r($allCSVFiles);
```